# How to change the default color for file selector?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am implementing a GUI for my project and try to do some customize for my GUI (for example, color scheme).

I use the following codes for a file selector

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.m', 'Select a MATLAB code file');
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
else
   disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])
end
```

However, any of you have ideas to change the default system color used for the file selector? Thanks. A.

Comment: I think there is no 'easy' way of doing this. You could try using java version of uigetfile from [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4506-uigetfiles-with-java-interface), and change color using java.

Comment: Yes without Java Invocation, color change won't be easy